# Calculate indicator function from two-point-correlation function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-series, stochastic-integrals

### The problem

Let

$p(d)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \chi(x)\chi(x+d) {\rm d} x$.

Both $p$ and $\chi$ are $2\pi$-periodic, real valued, positive functions.

With the restriction that $\chi(x)$ can take only the values 0 or 1, is $\chi(x)$ except for a shift $s$ of the argument $\chi(x+s)$ uniquely determined by $p(d)$?

### What I have so far

Representing $\chi(x)$ as a Fourier series

$\chi(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty  C_k \exp({\rm i}kx)$

and inserting this in the integral gives

$p(d)= 2 \pi ( C_0^2 + 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty C_{-k}C_{k} \cos(k d))$.

Therefore $p(d)$ is an even function. This is understandable, as changing $+d$ to $-d$ in the first equation can be compensated by shifting the bounds of the integral (admissible because of periodicity) and the commutativity of the product. So knowing $p(d)$ and its cosine-Fourier expansion coefficients $D_{0\ldots \infty}$

$p(d)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty D_k \cos(k d)$

with real coefficients $D_k$ allows by comparing coefficients to identify products of Fourier coefficients $C_k$ of $\chi(x)$,

$D_k = 4 \pi C_{-k}C_{k}\quad \rm{for}\quad k>0$

$D_0 = 2 \pi C_0^2\quad \rm{for}\quad k=0 $

This is of course not sufficient to identify $C_k$. Usually, higher moments are required. But if I constrain $\chi(x)$ to the value 0 or 1, is it possible to determine $C_k$?

To check this, the Fourier series of $\chi(x)$ must converge for all $x$ to either 0 or 1. How can I put this mathematically and check whether it determines $\chi(x)$?

Comment: I've changed the name to indicator function because, while characteristic function is synonymous, it is also has another meaning in probability theory. However, your post makes your meaning clear pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

You still have the problem that shifting the argument of $\chi$ by a constant that isn't a period of $\chi$ will change $\chi$ but not $p$. In particular, if we write $\chi(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\chi_ne^{in\chi}$ so $\chi_{-n}=\chi_n^\ast$, you can show $p(d)=2\pi\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}|\chi_n|^2e^{-ind}$, which is invariant under $\chi_n\mapsto\chi_n\exp in\theta$ (as is $\chi_{-n}=\chi_n^\ast$), which is equivalent to the periodicity-preserving replacement $\chi(x)\mapsto\chi(x+\theta)$.

Comment: That is correct. I forgot to mention that $\chi$ is to be determined up to the arbitrary shift of the argument. I will update the question, thank you. As I see it, removing the shift does not determine the Fourier coefficients of $\chi$.